# Prove that $f_n(x)$ converges to f point wisely on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

Let $f_n(x) = x^n(1-x), x\in [0,1] \\ f(x) =0 , x\in [0,1]$

$(1)$ Prove that $f_n(x)$ converges to f point wisely on $[0,1]$

$(2)$ Does $f_n \rightrightarrows
f$ on $[0,1]$

Using the following definitions:

[image]

**My Attempt at the solution:**

$(1)$

$f_n(x) = x^n(1-x), x\in [0,1] \\ |f_n(x) -f(x)| < \epsilon \\ \forall \epsilon >0 , 0 \le x \le 1 \\ |x^n(1-x) -0 | \\ x^n -x^{n+1} < \epsilon \\ \log(x^n)-\log(x^{n+1}) < \log(\epsilon)\\ n \log(x) -(n+1) \log(x) < \log(\epsilon) \\ n > \frac{log(\epsilon) + (n+1) \log(x)}{\log(x)} \\ N = \lceil \frac{log(\epsilon) + (n+1) \log(x)}{\log(x)}
 \rceil +1$

$(2)$

$M_n = \sup \{ x^n -x^{n+1}, x \in [0,1] \\ \text{ let } n=2 \\ \sup \{x^2-x^3: x\in [0,1] \} \\ \sup(0,1) \\ M_n =1$

Is this the correct procedure to use to solve the problem?

Comment: "Wisely"?${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: My approach would be to calculate the derivative in search of maximum of $f_n(x)$. In fact, I've already did, it's $\frac{n}{n+1}$, and the function sequence converges uniformly.

Comment: Your sixth line seems incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

For $n>0$,

$$f_n(0)=f_n(1)=0$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(0)=\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(1)=0$$
$$=f(0)=f(1)$$
Now consider $x\in (0,1)$ and a given small $0<\epsilon<1.$

it is clear that
$$|f_n(x)-0|\le x^n$$
and 
$$x^n<\epsilon \implies |f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

but
$$x^n<\epsilon \iff n>\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(x)}$$

thus for $$n>N=\lfloor \frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(x)}\rfloor+1$$

we will have
$$|f_n(x)-0|<x^n<\epsilon$$
For the uniform convergence,

$$f'_n(x)=nx^{n-1}(1-x)-x^n=x^{n-1}(n-nx-x)$$
the maximum is hit at $x_n=\frac{n}{n+1}$
you should compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)$.

Comment: I understand everything except the last line for the uniform convergence. $fn'(x) = nx^{n-1} -x^n*n+x^n \text{ how do you get } \Rightarrow \frac{n}{n+1} \text{ and } x^{n-1}(n-nx-x)$?

Comment: @Jon You look for $x$ such that $f'_n(x)=0$.

Comment: So we set $f_n'(x) =  nx^{n-1} - (n+1)x^n  = 0 $ .$ \\ $ $\Rightarrow nx^{n-1}-x^n*n +x^n = 0  $  What is the next step?

Comment: @Jon You need to find the maximum value of $f_n(x)$ when $0\le x\le 1$ using the derivative.

Comment: Why is the maximum value $f'_n(x) = \frac{n}{n+1}?$

Comment: The max value is attained when $x=\frac{n}{n+1}$. this max value is $f_n(\frac{n}{n+1})$. I think you will need Stirling formula.